# How to return Context from Fulfillment dialog flow

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, dialogflow-cx

I want to return a context variable  **service_desk_phonenumber** from the backend using web hook. I am able to return responses but not any **variables/context.**
Once the context variable is returned to dialog flow I want to set it as a parameter to **service_desk_phonenumber**.
So I can use the variable sent from backend in my dialog flow responses.
How to return context in fulfillment ?

```
  res = {
    "fulfillment_response": {
        "messages": [
            {
                "text": {
                    "text": [
                        text
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        'sessionInfo': { 'parameters': {'service_desk_phonenumber':'17372079207'}}
    }
```

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Could you please share the error code you are receiving

Comment: There is no error, It just shows the static response

Comment: @EduardoOrtiz How would you set/update or create new parameters and return them from a backend fulfillment?